# How can I export scraped information to CSV?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I have a code that with help of stackoverflow community (shoutout to @chitown88) I was able to run just fun.
The goal of the code is to scrape name, price and link from a website.
When I use print function it gives me the list perfectly. The code is as follows:

```
    import requests
    import csv
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    for x in range(0, 70):
        try:
            urls = 'https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/cat/2-%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C.html&pagesize[]=24&order[]=new&stock[]=1&page[]='  +str(x+1) +'&ajax=ok?_=1561559181560'
        source = requests.get(urls).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
        print('Page: %s' %(x+1))
        for figcaption in soup.find_all('figcaption'):
            price = figcaption.find('span', {'class':'new_price'}).text.strip()
            name = figcaption.find('a', class_='title').text
            link = figcaption.find('a', class_='title')['href']
            print('%s\n%s\n%s' %(price, name, link))
        except:
            break
```

now for the last part I need to export these information to a CSV file.
I tried to do so but no luck so far. Any suggestions?

I tried to implement CSV export function like this:

```
    import csv
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    csv_file = open('cms_scrape.csv', 'w')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['name', 'link', 'price'])
    for x in range(0, 70):
        try:
            urls = 'https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/cat/2-%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C.html&pagesize[]=24&order[]=new&stock[]=1&page[]=' + str(x + 1) + '&ajax=ok?_=1561559181560'
            source = requests.get(urls).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
            print('Page: %s' % (x + 1))
            for figcaption in soup.find_all('figcaption'):
               price = figcaption.find('span', {'class': 'new_price'}).text.strip()
               name = figcaption.find('a', class_='title').text
               link = figcaption.find('a', class_='title')['href']
               print('%s\n%s\n%s' % (price, name, link))
               csv_writer.writerow([name, link, price])
        except:
            break
    csv_file.close()
```

this code just gives me a csv file with name, link, price headers that all three are in column 1 and not column 1 to 3.

Comment: not a python person, but why not just modify your initial print output, i.e. `print('"%s","%s","%s"\n' %(price, name, link))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a standard [`csv.writer()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.writer) object to write a list as a row to a CSV file. The file should be encoded with `utf-8` format and have the `newline=''` parameter (see the documentation).

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['name', 'link', 'price'])

    for x in range(1, 101):
        urls = f'https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/cat/2-%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C.html&pagesize[]=24&order[]=new&stock[]=1&page[]={x}&ajax=ok?_=1561559181560'

        source = requests.get(urls).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

        print(f'Page: {x}')
        figcaptions = soup.find_all('figcaption')

        if figcaptions:
            for figcaption in figcaptions:
                price = figcaption.find('span', {'class':'new_price'}).text.strip()
                name = figcaption.find('a', class_='title').text
                link = figcaption.find('a', class_='title')['href']

                csv_output.writerow([name, link, price])
        else:
            print("Finished")
            break
```

Also, I would recommend you use the newer string formatting by prefixing `f` in front of your string. You can then include variables directly in the text using `{}`.

You can break out of the loop when you detect that there are no `figcaption` entries present.

This would give you a CSV file starting:

```
name,link,price
کاتریس پودر برنزه سان گلو 030,https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/آرایشی/آرایش-صورت/پودر-صورت/6288-کاتریس-پودر-برنزه-سان-گلو-030.html,"68,500 تومان"
اوتلت بورژوا مداد لب ادیشن 12,https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/آرایشی/آرایش-لب/مداد-لب/6286-اوتلت-بورژوا-مداد-لب-ادیشن-12.html,"57,000"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the following structure:

> csv.DictWriter

```py
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('cms_scrape.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['name', 'link', 'price']
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for x in range(0, 70):
        try:
            urls = 'https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/cat/2-%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C.html&pagesize[]=24&order[]=new&stock[]=1&page[]=' + str(
                x + 1) + '&ajax=ok?_=1561559181560'
            source = requests.get(urls).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
            print('Page: %s' % (x + 1))
            for figcaption in soup.find_all('figcaption'):
                price = figcaption.find('span', {'class': 'new_price'}).text.strip()
                name = figcaption.find('a', class_='title').text
                link = figcaption.find('a', class_='title')['href']
                print('%s\n%s\n%s' % (price, name, link))

                dict_row = dict(zip(fieldnames, [price, name, link]))

                csv_writer.writerow(dict_row)
        except:
            continue
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this code somehow breaks the for figcaption loop. Now the code only gives me the first product of each page and also CSV headers are still all in column 1.